# How to remove ComboBox Item from Collection by pressing Del Key?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to remove selected item from ComboBox Collection:
I wrote a buttonClick:

```
cb01.Items.Remove(cb01.SelectedItem);.
```

This deletes the item, but next time I open the Form - the item appears again.
Please help.

Comment: How you load the ComboBox items?

Comment: items are typed manually in design time as a collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `KeyDown` event for your ComboBox  and then

```
private void cb01_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
      if(cb01.SelectedIndex != -1)
         cb01.Items.Remove(cb01.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Above will remove items from comboBox but if you add items on designed time when you load the application again you can see all the items again.

check your `InitializeComponent()` method. you can see something like below.

```
 this.cb01.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item13"});
```

when you load the application again, it will call `InitializeComponent` and call above method to add items.

To avoid this issue. You can use bound data source. e.g you can take items from database. and when you delete you can delete it from database. next time you load the application it only show the items in the database.

Comment: I think he is doing that in Keydown event because one of his statement says `cb01.Items.RemoveAt(0); //removes allways first item`

Comment: Ok, I think, I'll try with a new question. ThanksToEveryOne.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if(cb01.SelectedItem != null)
    cb01.Items.Remove(cb01.SelectedItem);
```

Why i did checking?

Since in last line you said

```
cb01.Items.RemoveAt(cb01.SelectedIndex); // error: Value of '-1' is not valid...
```

-1 is the index of combo when no item is selected. So i checked for selected item first. If found will go in if statement.

Comment: @Buena: How are you providing/binding items to combobox?

Comment: I typed a colection in design time

Comment: So, edited the question. Item is removed by a buttonClick, but next time I open the Form - it appears again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `comboBox1` with the name of your combobox and bind its `KeyDown` event

```
void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int currentItem = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && currentItem != -1)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(currentItem);

        if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0) 
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = (currentItem > 0 ? currentItem - 1 : currentItem);
    }
}
```

This will select the next item in list after removing it, or do nothing if there are either no items in the comboBox or no item is selected.

Comment: No, it does not remove the item. Next time i open the combo - the item appears.

Comment: Something must be wrong in your code somewhere else then, because in the app I threw together in order to answer this it works flawlessly... I'll edit and provide the complete source.

Comment: what could be wrong? I have only one Combo on a form, and only one KeyDown event.